# How to use swiftlint command and Xcode Script when .swiftlint.yml file not in the same folder with project.xcodeproj?

Tags: xcode, swiftlint

I use [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) to control the code style of my project, it is working fine almost all the time. But I met a little trouble: when the `.swiftlint.yml` file not in the same folder with the project file '.xcodeproj', if I use command `swiftlint autocorrect` or use Xcode build to use [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) I need change `.swiftlint.yml` every time. The below is the details:

1. My project structure like below：

> ```
> > SampleProject
> >     ├── .swiftlint.yml
> >     ├── SampleProject
> >     │   ├── Frameworks
> >     │   ├── Info.plist
> >     │   ├── SampleProject
> >     │   ├── SampleProject.xcodeproj
> >     │   └── SampleProjectTests
> >     ├── SampleProject.xcworkspace
> >     ├── Configuration
> >     ├── CommonFoundation
> >     │   ├── CommonFoundation
> >     │   ├── CommonFoundation.xcodeproj
> >     │   └── CommonFoundationTests
> >     ├── Gemfile
> >     ├── Gemfile.lock
> >     ├── Podfile
> >     ├── Podfile.lock
> >     ├── Pods
> >     ├── README.md
> >     ├── fastlane
> >     └── release.sh
> ```

the `.swiftlint.yml` in the root path, but `SampleProject.xcodeproj` in the sub folder;

2. I've installed SwiftLint via `brew install swiftlint`;
3. I've add `SwiftLint Script` with below code in Xcode for project `SampleProject.xcodeproj`:

   ```
   if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
   swiftlint --config ../.swiftlint.yml
   else
   echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, 'brew install swiftlint' or download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
   fi
   ```

[image]

4. `.swiftlint.yml` code as below:

   ```
         disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
           - colon
           - comma
           - control_statement
           - line_length
           - type_body_length
           - function_body_length
           - cyclomatic_complexity
         opt_in_rules: # some rules are only opt-in
           - empty_count
         included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
             - ./SampleProject/Manager/Configs.swift

         excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
           - Carthage
           - Pods
         analyzer_rules: # Rules run by `swiftlint analyze` (experimental)
           - explicit_self

         force_cast: warning # implicitly
         force_try:
           severity: warning # explicitly
         type_body_length:
           - 300 # warning
           - 400 # error
         # or they can set both explicitly
         file_length:
           warning: 1000
           error: 1500
         type_name:
           min_length: 4 # only warning
           max_length: # warning and error
             warning: 40
             error: 50
           excluded: iPhone # excluded via string
         identifier_name:
           min_length: # only min_length
             error: 3 # only error
           excluded: # excluded via string array
             - i
             - j
             - id
             - GlobalAPIKey
         reporter: "xcode" # reporter type (xcode, json, csv, checkstyle, junit, html, emoji, sonarqube, markdown)
   ```
5. When I build project with Xcode with SwiftLint with file `SampleProject/SampleProject/Manager/Configs.swift`, I need update the `included` item in `.swiftlint.yml` as below:

   ```
     included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
         - ./SampleProject/Manager/Configs.swift
   ```
6. When I run command 'swiftlint autocorrect' with SwiftLint with file `SampleProject/SampleProject/Manager/Configs.swift`, I need update the `included` item in `.swiftlint.yml` as below:

   ```
     included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
         - SampleProject/SampleProject/Manager/Configs.swift
   ```

I want find a way to help on this is do not change `.swiftlint.yml` file but command 'swiftlint autocorrect' and Xcode build are working fine with SwiftLint.

Comment: Did you find an answer?